# gcc TemplateClass<::GlobalSymbol> error on <::

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

For some reason gcc does not like when template parameter is a global namespace symbol, i.e.

```
TemplateClass<::GlobalSymbol>
```

It works when I do

```
TemplateClass< ::GlobalSymbol>
```

That is, gcc does not like to see <::

Is it possible to prevent without modifying sources (which are autogenerated)?

UPD: I don't want to modify sources. I found that -fpermissive seems to change this to a warning instead of error, but haven't found yet how to enable it from code (using pragmas for example).

UPD: Well, I found that

```
 #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-fpermissive"
```

does the trick, anyway I accept the answer that helped me to find this out.

Comment: Do you want to fix it in the source or not? Pragma's are part of the source.

Comment: Yes, but I can include the autogenerated source file into another file and wrap the include with pragmas. I could consider compiling autogenerated file with -fpermissive but cmake doesn't allow per-file cxx flags, only per module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<:` is a [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) which is equivalent to `[`, thus the error. Since you don't want to modify the code a workaround is to use `-fpermissive` command-line argument or pragma to G++ (it actually gives you a hint):

```
test.cpp:9:16: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

Comment: @queen3: well, you already know the workaround: separate `<` and `::` with a space

Comment: The exact name is "alternative token", since they aren't all digraphs (and the Wiki article you link to is particularly bad).  As for the workaround---you've already found it: just use a space between the `<` and the `::`.  (The committee introduced a special rewrite rule for the `>>` in `vector<vector<T>>`; maybe this case should get one as well.)

Comment: @queen3: Sorry, haven't noticed that you don't want to modify the source code first time. Updated the answer for completeness anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With gcc 4.6 I get the following error:

```
graphs.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
graphs.cpp:9:15: error: ‘<::’ cannot begin a template-argument list [-fpermissive]
graphs.cpp:9:15: note: ‘<:’ is an alternate spelling for ‘[’. Insert whitespace between ‘<’ and ‘::’
graphs.cpp:9:15: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

So, -fpermissive is the way to go. [EDIT: I see now that you added that you already found this]

Else, since you mentioned that the sources are auto-generated, you could add a post processing step. For example using `sed`

```
sed -i 's,<::,< ::,g' filename.cpp
```

or something similar in e.g. python. But only if you are sure you never use <:: for something else.